# AJAX по кнопке срабатывает только один раз

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

По клику на кнопку, ajaxом подменяется часть контента на странице. В том числе и кнопка, по которой срабатывает функция. После этого функция по кнопке уже не вызывается, хотя она имеет нужный селектор. Не подменять эту кнопку в моем приложении довольно сложно, можно ли как-то обойти эту проблему и заставить кнопку работать повторно?

```
$('.remove-from-cart').on('click', function(){
    var data = {
        product_id: $(this).attr('data-product-id')
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/remove-from-cart/',
        data: data,
        success: function(data){
            $('#shoping-cart-widget').html(data)
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код

Comment: Добавил код, но мне кажется, что  он мало что иллюстрирует)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно, добавь этот скрипт в файле ответа, тогда он у тебя будет вешаться на кнопку снова и снова, тем самым будет работать бесконечно

Ещё есть вариант начало функции не правильно выглядит

```
$('а тут родительский селектор').on('click', '.remove-from-cart', function(){
```

.on для этого и создан что бы динамично добавлять обработчик на вновь появившиеся элементы

Comment: Юху! Вот этот вариант работает и выглядит адекватнее того, что ты предложил в первый раз)) Спасибо большое)

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров _Добавил код, но мне кажется, что он мало что иллюстрирует)_ - не зря всегда нужно добавлять код :-)